# Sudden BSoD causing the whole machine to stop responding

Tags: windows-7, motherboard

There was a sudden crash, Blue screen of death on my pc. But, after the memory dump on 20% the whole system turned off itself leaving only the power led on.

After that I tried turning off and on again but there was no activity except all the cooling fan were running and the lit power led. There is nothing on the screen. There isnt even any beep sound.

Where should I start troubleshooting my system? I dont have any second machine to try and replacing things.

I think its a motherboard issue.

Another thing is that, the BSoD was frequent now a days. But I didnt bother.

**Here is what happened**

1. I was working.
2. BSoD shows up
3. Display goes black while the memory dump was on 20%. Monitor power was up, its just there was nothing to display.
4. There was nothing happening, like no hard disk activity. So, I cold restarted the system.
5. Nothing shows up on the display. No hard disk activity. There even wasnt any beep sound.
6. Tried restarting it several times. But the result remains the same.

My system : Core 2 Duo, 2GB DDR2, Intel G41, Radeon 4670, Windows 7

**Solved ::**
It was a motherboard failure.

Comment: A few more details might help

Comment: @dave-m Updated. Should I add anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware problem. Perhaps hard disk related. I'd start by examining your HD. Did you hear any noises or creaks prior to the original BSOD?

Comment: No, there wasn't any sound. I tried after disconnecting hard disk ,after the crash, but nothing has changed. In fact, monitor should display the basic boot up things, ram check etc etc. But, there is nothing on my display. I am wondering why there isn't any beep sound. Any idea?

Comment: Could be many things: motherboard failure (rare), power failure, a short somewhere... Have you recently added any new hardware? Have you rattled the machine? Hard to tell from the info you supplied. But ultimately, this is a hardware issue

Comment: The rare one, motherboard failure.

Comment: Really? How did you find out?

Comment: Replaced every components to another system, this one was the only thing that broke it. Then I took it to a service center and they concluded the same.